# Pagination coming from AJAX request not working properly -- Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6 -- Jquery Ajax

Here's the point

I'm having a search input placed in my navbar there's an eventlistener('keyup') on it.

Everytime keyup is fired, an AJAX GET request is send to

```
url : '{{action('PostController@searchAdmin')}}'
```

**From web.php :**  `Route::get('/search/admin', 'PostController@searchAdmin')`;

I made the return of that action a partial with data

```
return view('back.partials.searchResult', ['posts' => $posts, 'trashed' => $trashed]);
```

And I **replace the content** of the main tag **with that partial**

Everything is working properly except when the result count is greater than 10 (the breakpoint of pagination).

Pagination control links are all pointing to "search/admin?page=x" and when I click on it, this error is showing

```
Undefined variable: posts
```

I used `$posts->links()` to show the controls

Comment: Obviously `$posts` variable is not initialized when results count is greater than 10. You should try to debug the code where `$posts` is initialized with values.

Comment: Well... I think it comes from the fact that all my variables filling are in a 
`if ($request->ajax())`statement

Comment: I changed everything !
It works, except when i change the current page with the pagination...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution so I post it

**In web.php**

```
Route::get('/search', function(Request $request) {
    $search = $request->search;
    $trashed = Post::trash()->count();
    $posts = Post::notTrash()
        ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . "%")
        ->orWhere('post_type' , 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->paginate(10);


    $posts->withPath('?search=' . $search);
    return view('back.partials.searchResult', ['posts' => $posts, 'trashed' => $trashed, 'search' => $search]);
});
```

This code was for test purpose and will be soon exported in a new controller called SearchController

**In my PostController**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    // GET parameters
    $paginate = $request->input('paginate') ?? 10;
    $search = $request->input('search') ?? null;

    if($search !== null) {
        $posts = $this->checkCategories($paginate, $search);
    } else {
        $posts = Post::notTrash()->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate($paginate);
    }
    $trashed = Post::trash()->count();
    $posts->withPath('?search=' . $search);

    return view('back.index', ['posts' => $posts, 'trashed' => $trashed, 'search' => $search]);
}
```

**Working with**

```
private function checkCategories($paginate, $search)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        if(strpos(strtolower($category->name), $search) === false) {
// @TODO: Change for stripos 
            $posts = Post::notTrash()
                ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('post_type', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->paginate($paginate);
        } else {
            return Category::find($category->id)->posts()->paginate($paginate);
        }
    }

    return $posts;

}
```

The index method now accept Request to handle get parameters when they are some.

**In my views**

```
   @if($search !== null)
        {{ $posts->appends($search)->links() }}
    @else
        {{ $posts->links() }}
    @endif
```

Now replace

```
{{ $posts->links() }}
```

The solution was `$var->**withPath()**` and handling **GET parameters**